# Percentage positioning to fit in all screens

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am making the layout of a web page that I want it to have the same look in all screens. The page I am working on, has three parts, header, main, and footer, which I want to header to be on the top of the screen. main and footer sticks to the bottom of the page.

Here is what I want to do:

1. I made the header to in the top but I couldn't add percentage to the main and footer section.
2. Also in the header there is a div which called 'div5', I want it to sticks at the bottom of the parent div which is main or middle box.
3. in the footer I have three boxes which want to have them in left, right and center.

Can you have a look at the [linked site](http://mersadesign.com/demo/percentage.html) and let me know how to fix these problems.

Comment: Please upload the code on your webspace and make it publicly accessible, so we can easily watch the source code.

Comment: JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/NAUnP/

Answer (score 1):

percentage heights only work if you set the parent element to have a height.

( the elements will ask "percentage of what?" )

Here we set a height to the body

**css**

```
<style type="text/css">

      html,body { height:100%;}

      #header { display:block; height:10%; }
      #main   { display:block; height:80%; }
      #footer { display:block; height:10%; }

</style>
```

**markup**

```
   <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
   </body>
```

Comment: Not to mention this would be an unusual desire for a UI since width is usually the issue and not height.

Answer (score 0):

By doing these you are making you div 2,3 & 4 overlap. make sure that even that is taken care of. and Yes you must consider an option of Css media queries. Please go through the demo [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/adaptive-design/final.html)